# Mocha test passing even when assertion is failing

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, assertion

I need to run an assertion on a JS object that I am getting. The issue here is that even when my assertion fails, the test is still shown to be passing; how can I fix it?

**Code:**

```
  var expect = require('chai').expect
    const sslCertificate = require('get-ssl-certificate')

    describe('ssl certificate verification',()=>{
    it('verifies the issuer of the certificate',()=>{
        sslCertificate.get('instagram.com').then(function (certificate) {
           console.log(typeof certificate.issuer)
           console.log(certificate.issuer.O)
           console.log(certificate.issuer.CN)
           console.log(certificate.subject.CN)

           expect(certificate.issuer).to.include({CN: 'DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA'});
           expect(certificate.issuer).which.is.an('object').to.haveOwnProperty('CN')
        })
    })
})
```

**Terminal Command:**

```
mocha myFile.js
```

**Output**

```
ssl certificate verification
    √ verifies the issue of the certificate


  1 passing (46ms)

object
DigiCert Inc
DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
*.instagram.com
```

**Failing Assertion, But Passing Test Output**

```
 expect(certificate.issuer).to.include({CN: 'a'});



    ssl certificate verification
    √ verifies the issue of the certificate


  1 passing (43ms)

object
DigiCert Inc
DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
*.instagram.com
(node:13712) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: AssertionError: expected { Object (C, O, ...) } to have property 'CN' of 'a', but got 'DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA'
    at D:\a10\cypress\integration\ssli5_2v4\bypassFlow\new.js:15:42
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:13712) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:13712) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would happen when you are working with asynchronous code (and promises). From your test code it appears that the method sslCertificate.get() returns a Promise. This promise would get resolved (successfully executed) or rejected (throw an error) asynchronously. In JS the asynchronous execution starts only after the current synchronous execution pauses/completes.

In the context of your test, you pass a callback method when the promise resolves (using .then()). This callback gets executed only after the promise is resolved and since your test code would not pause for this execution, it completes successfully - meaning sslCertificate.get('instagram.com').then(callback) never throws any error or exception. After the test is executed, the promise gets a chance to resolve and now asynchronously executes your callback. Therefore, you get the UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: AssertionError.

This can be handled by using mocha async tests in two ways:

**Method 1: Using async/await (my personal recommendation for readability):**

1. Make your test function async.
2. await for the promise to resolve.
3. Perform your assertions.

Here's some code:

```
it('verifies the issuer of the certificate', async ()=>{ // This tells the test contains asynchronous code
    const certificate = await sslCertificate.get('instagram.com'); // await gives a chance for the promise to resolve (in which case the certificate will be returned) or reject (in which case an exception will be thrown)

    // You can now perform your assertions on the certificate
    expect(certificate.issuer).to.include({CN: 'DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA'});
    expect(certificate.issuer).which.is.an('object').to.haveOwnProperty('CN');
});
```

**Method 2: Using done callback from mocha - NOT my favorite for your usecase - used when there are callbacks but no promises involved**

1. Add an argument called 'done' for the test function (the name is really arbitrary).
2. Perform all required assertions within the callback function passed to 'then()'.
3. Finally call done().

Adding the 'done' argument forces mocha to wait until the callback done() is called. Now if your assertions fail, done() will never be called and the test would fail with a timeout error (and of course with the unhandled rejection error in the console). Still, the test would fail.

Sample Code:

```
it('verifies the issuer of the certificate',(done)=>{ // Forces mocha to wait until done() is called
    sslCertificate.get('instagram.com').then(function (certificate) {

       expect(certificate.issuer).to.include({CN: 'DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA'});
       expect(certificate.issuer).which.is.an('object').to.haveOwnProperty('CN');
       done(); // All assertions done.
    });
});
```

More details from official docs: https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code

Comment: There is an advantage when using the "done" approach. You will get the time the test case took to complete.